# Отличия MySQL от Oracle DataBase в javaee проекте

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

Расскажите, пожалуйста, *кратко и по сути вопроса* про основные отличия данных **СУБД**; если веб-приложение разрабатывается на **java**, то какие **сопутствующие технологии** нужно будет выбирать в зависимости от СУБД и на что это влияет.

Прошу в ответах опираться на **личный опыт** и не копировать информацию, которую спокойно можно найти в гугле. Интересуют именно нюансы работы с каждой из СУБД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кратко и по сути, но указать  нюансы - хм-м-м :). Как говорят в Одессе - это две большие разницы.
Если кратко - Oracle поддерживает огромные массивы данных и позволяет с ними достаточно быстро работать. Также обладает фичами, которые как раз интересны для таких случаев.
MySQL хорошо работает с небольшими базами - в пределах десятков (ну может нескольких сотен) гигов.
Ну и цена вопроса тоже имеет смысл.